# I'm trying to login in a php site with an android interface, but I don't know how to send data

Tags: java, php, android, post, get

I'm trying to log into a site and obtain the code back, but i'm getting "invalid password or login", but I'm sure they are both ok

here's part of my code:

```
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www3.mackenzie.com.br/tia/index2.php");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
```

I'm trying to acess this page: 
http://www3.mackenzie.com.br/tia/index2.php

I'm not sure if I should put "username" and "password" or something else?  how can I identify that?
what could be my problem guys?

thanks for your help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight modification on Maxwell Weru's answer, I believe his url is wrong. & added one param.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www3.mackenzie.com.br/tia/verifica.php");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alumat", username));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("unidade", "001"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Comment: Using Chrome's Developer Console i attempted to login(just dummy values). From this i was able to see all transactions between the browser and the website. I looked for "post"'s and the first one after you attempt to login is to the "http://www3.mackenzie.com.br/tia/verifica.php" with the three params i listed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the site you provided, i think this is the way you should write your code

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www3.mackenzie.com.br/tia/index2.php");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alumat", username));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Pay particular empphasis on the value pairs added